# Maven project use Tomcat web application server in IntelliJ IDEA: gc overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Trying to launch a maven project in IntelliJ IDEA with Apache Tomcat web server. Edit **Configurations** \ **Tomcat Server(Local)**

Apparently the IntelliJ IDEA gets stuck at parsing java and ends with the error

> Error:java: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

How can I debug this, are there some logs being generated?

Comment: How much memory have you allocated to IntelliJ?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam 

These are the settings
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options
```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops```

Comment: what is the value of the property MAVEN_OPTS, if any ?